# Windows (COM) API behaving differently w/o specific library

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, com

It seems that the Windows API behaves differently depending on whether or not I link in a specific library. Unfortunately, it's a pretty big library which makes it hard to track the issue down and I don't have a real clue where to start.

I can reproduce this behaviour for several APIs. For example, I'm using the COM-based shell API to determine the "open with" applications for a specific file extension.

```cpp
CComPtr<IEnumAssocHandlers> enumerator;
HRESULT hr = SHAssocEnumHandlers(L".jpg", ASSOC_FILTER_RECOMMENDED, &enumerator);

for (CComPtr<IAssocHandler> handler; enumerator->Next(1, &handler, nullptr) == S_OK; handler.Release()) {
    CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> wAppName;
    handler->GetName(&wAppName);

    std::wcout << std::wstring(wAppName) << std::endl;
}
```

This works flawlessly in a test application that doesn't do anything else. If I link against the said library, it stops working and instead of the UWP app entries it just prints *TWINUI*.
Actually opening the application then using `IAssocHandler::Invoke` also behaves differently and in case of Adobe Photoshop it suprisingly signs the user out of the Adobe account (this is always reproducible - perhaps some license protection that comes into play because of a different context?).
Another example I experienced in the past was with the WIC (Windows Imaging Component) API, also COM-based, which returned an error about codecs being unavailable (which were available in the minimal test).

So the question is: Are there compiler flags or macros that could cause these issues? (e.g. WinSDK versioning)
What else could I look for?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: There is no *"make COM do different things"* compiler switch or preprocessor macro. You're going to have to produce a [mcve].

Comment: It's possible that the other library is initializing COM in a way different from the way your program does it.

Comment: What call are you using to initialize COM?

Comment: I can't produce a minimal reproducible example, because the library is too big to easily drop out things. That's why I'm looking for clues. The other library isn't using COM and in my app I'm using `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);` to initialize COM. Also, all API calls in my app happen in a thread that is exclusively used by the app (not the library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that loading the OpenBLAS library caused the problem. It's even reproducible with a minimal example:

```cpp
// code in the original post --> works

LoadLibraryA("libopenblas.dll");
// not reproducible with LoadLibraryExA("libopenblas", NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
// to avoid calling DllMain

// code in the original post --> doesn't work
```

So it seems that something in the OpenBLAS library breaks the Windows API. Suprisingly, removing the library also fixed a bunch of other problems we were not able to fix in the past and seemed unrelated on first glance.

We use a pretty old version (0.2.9; `DYNAMIC_ARCH` enabled) though, so it might be fixed in a later version, but since we don't need OpenBLAS anymore at all, I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Hi jhx, feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).